# How do I validate one value entered in one form control is greater than one entered in another form control in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have two form field **minAmount** and **maxAmount** in reactive form in Angular. I need to make sure that the **maxAmount** is greater than  **minAmount**. I've tried using:

```
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    minAmount: [undefined],
    maxAmount: [undefined, [Validators.min(this.form.get('minAmount').value)]]

  });
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you put together a stackblitz?

Answer (score 3):

you need make a custom validator over the formGroup or a customValidator and check the two values. If only check the minAmount, when you change the max, Angular don't check the values.

If you make a custom validator over the fromGroup, take account that each change in any input of the formGroup, "call" to the validator function

```
  form = this.formBuilder.group({
    minAmount: [undefined,this.customValidator()],
    maxAmount: [undefined, this.customValidator()]
  }); 

  customValidator()
  {
    return (control:FormControl)=>
    {
      const form=control.parent
      if (form)
      {
        const min=form.get('minAmount');
        const max=form.get('maxAmount');
        return min.value && max.value && +max.value<+min.value?{error:'min malue'}:null
      }
    }
  }

 <div *ngIf="form.get('minAmount')?.errors.error 
          || form.get('maxAmount')?.errors.error">
      error
 </div>
```

or

```
  form = this.formBuilder.group({
    minAmount: [undefined],
    maxAmount: [undefined]
  },{validators:this.customValidatorGroup()}); 

  customValidatorGroup()
  {
    return (form:FormGroup)=>{
        const min=form.get('minAmount');
        const max=form.get('maxAmount');
        return min.value && max.value && +max.value<+min.value?{error:'min malue'}:null
    }
  }

  <div *ngIf="form.errors?.error">
        error group
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    minAmount: [undefined, Validators.required],
    maxAmount: [undefined, Validators.required]
  }, { validator: findMaxamount }
  );
```

And create your own validator like

```
findMaxamount(form: FormGroup){
  const min = form.get('minAmount').value;
  const max = form.get('maxAMount').value;
  return max > min ? true : false;
}
```